# Sorting a List of Pairs java

Tags: java, java-8

I've List with Pairs in it. I want to sort them according to the keys first and if keys are same then sort according to the values.

I tried following code but throws an exception  incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T

```
 List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Pair::getKey).thenComparingInt(Pair::getValue);
```

Error :

> **incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T**
>                                                                                        (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
>         method getKey in class Pair cannot be applied to given types
>           required: no arguments
>           found: Object
>           reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>
> where T,K,V are type-variables:
>       T extends Object declared in method comparingInt(ToIntFunction)
>       K extends Object declared in class Pair
>       V extends Object declared in class Pair

Comment: Which library / package is `Pair` coming from ?

Comment: javafx.util.Pair

Comment: As a side note, unless you’re truly developing a JavaFX application, you shouldn’t use that type, as you’re adding a significant dependency. Starting with JDK 11, JavaFX is not even included by default.

Comment: Can we sort key in reverse way and values in ascending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to help the compiler infer the appropriate type for the comparator:

```
list.sort(Comparator.<Pair<Integer, Integer>>comparingInt(Pair::getKey).thenComparingInt(Pair::getValue));
```

Comment: Slightly simpler syntax: `list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Pair<Integer,Integer>::getKey) .thenComparingInt(Pair::getValue));`